# Video freezes 16.04 Skylake Nvidia 950M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel, freeze

since I bought this machine I have had freezes. Not too often usually, but if I use the vlc player enough it will freeze up my machine.

In my drivers settings I have the Nvidia driver and an unknown device intel-microcode, it says.

I tried updating to the very newest Nvidia driver but it actually seems to be worse now. Will play with the unknown device to see if that's the problem.

Can anyone give me some advice? Been putting up with this for far too long, its such a pain.

Comment: The unknown device won't fix anything. If you update to the latest BIOS it will upgrade the microcode anyway.

Comment: When it freezes, can you still get to `tty1`? And does the REISUB trick work?